# How to take a screenshot of an entire scroll element?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, html, screenshot

I searched the Internet to find a way to do it,
but I didn’t find anything that works.

I use the web version of Tinder app. There's a chat section inside a div and I want to take a pic of the entire chat in just one shot. The div  element, which has a scroll function, is inside of this red border:

[image: Screenshot of the page]

I usually use Chrome, but I can use Firefox or any browser that could do it. Is it possible?

Comment: if you using chrome use `Full Page screen capture`.

Comment: @usrNotFound unfortunately it doesn't work too.  I had already tried before. But I got the problem and answered my own question :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK. I had an insight and could solve the problem, hehe.

I went to div properties and changed the 'height' in CSS to 500%. Voilà! Then I could use "Screenshot Node" feature on Firefox. It was not working before because the height was on 100% so the screenshot node only toke the visible part on screen, not all element :D

Answer (score 12):

From Chrome dev tools > Device Toolbar, you can focus the required element and click on **Capture full size screenshot**.

[image: Screenshot of screenshot capture]

Comment: Best solution without requiring any extensions!

Comment: You can do this without entering device mode by opening the dev console, hitting ctrl+shift+p (windows) to open the command prompt and typing "Screenshot". Select full size screenshot and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Nimbus Screenshot & Screen Video Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nimbus-screenshot-screen/bpconcjcammlapcogcnnelfmaeghhagj?hl=en) for most of my screenshots and has many options to capture different parts of the page, there are other options but this is the best I've found for sure.

Comment: I already tried this extension but didn't work in my case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you can use `Capture node screenshot` in the ***Developer Tools*** Interface (navigating the F12), in the ***Elements tab***.

[image: Capture node screenshot]

Comment: It doesn't scroll the node if it has a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the scroll area is not a browser viewport scroll. To confirm, scroll down the page and look for a full viewport scrollbar on the right. For instance on this page, its easy to see.

Likely there is overflow scroll trickery going on within a content area. The screenshot tool will scroll the viewport scroll, but not this content area overflow scroll. There is no viewport scroll, so the tool thinks there is nothing additional to screenshot.

You can make the screenshot tool work again, by removing the css that makes the overflow scroll on the content div. Use the browser dev tools and just uncheck the css.

There will likely only be a couple things. An overflow hidden on a parent, then scroll and height assignments on children.

Once removed, the page will scroll like a normal page, then the screenshot tool will work.

Its annoying, but once you figure it out its pretty quick.